# Images not show in all devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i am using a image in my home page. But it's not working properly in all other devices.
This is my code

```
<div class="team-carousel">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 team-type">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/about-us"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/dr_baruch_twersky.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="doctor-1" id="image-border"/></a>
                    <div class="member-content">
                        <div class="member-name">
                            <h6>Dr. Baruch Twersky</h6>
                            <p>Doctor of Dental Medicine</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "not working properly"?? i see a "get_template_directory_uri" so i assume you are using wordpress? 

What exactly is happening?

Comment: yes, Actually image not show in mobile divice

Comment: Without looking at CSS, i cant really see whats happening BUT, the next best thing i can say is, use GOOGLE CHROME inspector, and use the mobile emulation tools, and change the width slowly to see where it is, that the image disappears. Then from there, look at the code/css and see whats happening. Maybe its being hidden by css/boostrap or something

Comment: problem solved, thanks
Actually some class was conflict